# Simulink: Matlab Embedded Function Code Error

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have the following code in an embedded matlab function in simulink:

```
 function rad = fcn(lenkwinkel)
if lenkwinkel < 0
    rad=[0 1 0 0];
elseif lenkwinkel > 0
    rad=[1 0 0 0];
else
    rad=[0 0 0 0];
end
```

In the simulation I have the "lenkwinkel" variable connected to the MATLAB Function Block,which is connected to a Mux block with 4 ports.

I am trying to use the function to send a vector with 4 binary elements to the Mux block, which then should split it into 4 signals. Unfortunately, this is not working. When I try to run this, I get:

> Inferred size ('[1 4]') for data 'rad' (#44) does not match back
>   propagated size ('[4]') from Simulink.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean DeMux?  If the demux is connect to a Scope then the model as described works for me (in R2013b).  What do you have connected to the output of the demux?

Comment: Hello there. Yes, I am sorry. I do mean DeMux. On the left side, the DeMux connects to the function and on the right side it splits into 4 port, where each connects to a product block. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you mean DeMux as well, please correct us if that is incorrect.  From the looks of it, the MATLAB Function block has determined that the size of `rad` is `1-by-4` since that is the size of the value assigned to it.  However, something else seems to think that the output should be of size `[4]` or `4-by-1`.  Have you manually specified the output of the MATLAB Function block to have size `[4]` or the size of the demux to expect an input of size `[4]`?

You could either change the definition of `rad` to be 4-by-1 or the size specified to Simulink to be `[1, 4]`.

Comment: I see what you mean. I didn't know I had to manually set the output of the MATLAB function. Right-clicking the function block, selecting "Explore" and setting the output size to "[1 4]" did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: that works for me, but I'd prefer if the output size could be 'Inherited'. Do you have a suggestion for that? (Or is that a separate question?) Also... do you have any idea why taking a transpose doesn't solve the problem?